# Mysql create a general tablespace in a specific directory

Tags: mysql, linux, tablespace

I am trying to create a tablespace in a specific directory `/home/tareq178/data/` in my Linux Ubuntu 22.04.3 VM.
I am using the following command

```
CREATE TABLESPACE newspace2 ADD DATAFILE "/home/tareq178/data/newspace2.ibd" engine=InnoDB;
```

But it's giving me ar error

```
ERROR 3121 (HY000): The directory does not exist or is incorrect.
```

The path already exists and I have given the directory ownership to mysql.

[image: issue]

I have also specified innodb_directories in the "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" file

[image: innodb_directories]

And if I type

```
show variables like "innodb_directories"
```

I can see the directory has been added correctly.
[image: innodb_directories2]

Still I get the same error. My Mysql version is mysql

> Ver 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

How can I create a tablespace in a specific directory?

Comment: What is the TEXT result of SELECT @@version;  so we know which mysql you are running?  There is mysql, mariadb and percona server choices available.  Which one are you using or something else?

Comment: @WilsonHauck after typing SELECT @@version; I get "8.0.36-0ubuntu0.22.04.1"

Comment: This url has detailed check off type information to assist.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/general-tablespaces.html